# VB.Net SQL Server copy data from an on-the-fly-datatable into database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable

This is doing my crust in... Working in VB.net 2010 and 2013. I have a datatable which is created on the fly and I want to deposit said data into a table in my SQL Server database in the fastest possible way. Currently the only thing I can get to work is "insert into..." for each row in the datatable by creating the sql to insert each value into each field. What I'd like is for SqlServer.datatable = onTheFlyDataTable.

I've tried row by row, but I can't get that to work as the SQL I use for my server table is a "SELECT * FROM..." which is obviously read only.

What I did get to run without errors, was something like this, but it never wrote the data back to the SQL Server Database. I did run without errors, and the dtTEST as the end of it *did* contain all the rows I'd added - it just didn't write it back to the database. Even tried .AcceptChanges...

```
Dim sSYSsqlTEST As String = "SELECT * FROM MyDataBaseTable;"
Debug.Print(sSYSsqlTEST)

Dim cmdTEST As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sSYSsqlTEST, cNN)
Dim daTEST As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdTEST)
Dim dsTEST As DataSet = New DataSet
If Not IsNothing(daTEST) Then
    daTEST.Fill(dsTEST, "TEST")
End If
Dim dtTEST As DataTable = dsTEST.Tables("TEST")


For each dr as datarow in myOnTheFlyDataTable
    Dim workRow As DataRow = workTable.NewRow ()
    workRow = dr
    workTable.Rows.Add (workRow)
Next
```

Is what I'm trying to do achievable?

Based on Pradeep's response, I've altered to this but I get "The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.
"

```
Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(cNN)
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo." + sCUSTOMER + "_IMPORT"
With bulkCopy.ColumnMappings
    For x As Integer = 0 To iNOfields
    Debug.Print("Column " + x.ToString + " Datatype = " + dtIMPORT.Columns(x).DataType.ToString)
    .Add(dtIMPORT.Columns(x).ColumnName, "[FIELD " + x.ToString + "]")
    Next
End With
Try
    ' Write from the source to the destination.
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtIMPORT)
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    Debug.Print("")
End Try

End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is transfer your `DataTable` to the database then use the `SqlBulkCopy` class. You would achieve a much better performance.

Note that the table structures must be identical.

```
Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(yourConnection)
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.YourDataBaseTable" 
    With bulkCopy.ColumnMappings
        .Add("srcColumn1", "destColumn1")
        .Add("srcColumn2", "destColumn2")
        '-- and so on ...

    End With
    Try 
       yourConnection.open()
        ' Write from the source to the destination.
          bulkCopy.WriteToServer (myOnTheFlyDataTable)
       yourConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try 
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. I think my problem is that not all of the field types match: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination. This coulod be a problem as the on-the-flydatatable is taken from a spreadsheet which may set number as number, where some of them in my table are varchar(250). I may ty forcing the excel read to make them strings but not hopeful of this. IS there another way of doing row by row in case this won't work?

Comment: Yes, if your column definitions don't match then you can specify the column mapping information in the `ColumnMappings` property.

Comment: I updated the code above to show how column mapping information can be added. HTH.

Comment: Thanks - still getting mapping error. All the fields in my table are varchar(250) - all the columns in my datatable are system.string. A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

Comment: Atleast one of the columns is causing problems. Temporarily comment out that loop and put hardcoded field names. Add one column mapping at a time and run the program to see which column is causing problems and what is peculiar about that field.

Comment: Also reading about the `SqlBulkCopy` class might help. You might catch something from the documentation that we are missing. Read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I found the problem - the datatable had 21 columns, the database 20. I removed the superfluous column from the datatable and it worked fine. Thanks